# Windows 10: Michael Hartl Chapter3: Rspec Spec error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I am running the rspec spec/ command from the third chapter. Created the sample_app using command

```
rails new sample_app -T -database=postgresql
```

and when running the command rspec spec/ getting the below error.

```
C:\Users\ASUS PC\rails_projects\Sample_App>rspec spec
You must 'gem install win32console' to use colour on Windows
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- test/unit/assertions (LoadError)
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.0.1/lib/rspec/rails/adapters.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-rails-2.0.1/lib/rspec/rails.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
        from C:/Users/ASUS PC/rails_projects/Sample_App/spec/spec_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
        from C:/Users/ASUS PC/rails_projects/Sample_App/spec/controllers/pages_controller_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:306:in `load'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:306:in `block in load_spec_files'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:306:in `map'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:306:in `load_spec_files'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:18:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:55:in `run_in_process'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:46:in `run'
        from C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rspec-core-2.0.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
```

Looks like rails is looking for test directory which was not created.

Rspec Gem list:

```
rspec (2.0.1)
rspec-core (2.0.1)
rspec-expectations (2.0.1)
rspec-mocks (2.0.1)
rspec-rails (2.0.1)
rspec-support (3.4.1)
```

Gemfile Development and Test

```
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.3'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.0.0'

end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

end
```

Comment: The command is rspec spec

Comment: my bad, thanks @margo. edited the original message

Comment: Did you follow all the steps to install rspec, generate rspec:install, etc?

Comment: yes, i followed the instructions to install rspec and ran generate rspec:install

Comment: Do you have the gem in the development and test group in your Gemfile? Sorry for the basic questions but your issue sounds like a set up issue.

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually try to install the gem mentionned in the error ?

```
gem install win32console
```

Also it seems you still have some dependencies to the classical test framework. Did you check application.rb for any call to the `test` railties that would not be commented out ?

```
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
```

Shoud be commented

Comment: Cyril, the gem win32console is installed, and test_unit railtie is commented.
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"